# Update progress when loading to listview

Tags: android, listview

**Goal**

What I am trying to do is, query my pass in values to query my database and pass the results to my listview, however before the listview loads I would like to have a progress dialog showing progress of the downloading of the items.

**What I have done**

Query my database, display the progress dialog before updating the listview

**Problem**

The problem that I am encountering is the progress is not being published. and my connection lenght is -1. and i believe this is my problem

Please see code below. I am not exactly versed with publishing updates despite the reading so I would like if i could get some assistance.
Thanks

```
public class StudentAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {




@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressD = new ProgressDialog(retrievrSData.this);
        progressD.setMessage("Retrieving Results");
        progressD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressD.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressD.setProgress(0);
        progressD.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // THIS IS -1
            int fileLength = conection.getContentLength();


            HttpParams param = new BasicHttpParams();
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> inputArguments = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            if (firstName.equals("''") && !lastname.equals("''")) {
                inputArguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("l_name", lastname));
            } else if (!firstName.equals("''") && lastname.equals("''")) {
                inputArguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f_name", firstName));

            } else if (!firstName.equals("''") && !lastname.equals("''")) {
                inputArguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f_name", firstName));
                inputArguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("l_name", lastname));
            }


            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(param);
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http:// technologies.com/Das/getst.php");
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(inputArguments, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse) client.execute(request);


            int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 404) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(404, intent);
                finish();
            }
            if (status == 200) {

                if (fileLength > 0) {
                    publishProgress((int) (5 * 100 / fileLength));
                }

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Below is the progress update code.

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
        progressD.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressD.setMax(100);
        progressD.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
```

Comment: The content length is not available because by default Android request a GZIP compressed response.
Source: [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I cannot get a progress bar to work?

Comment: you have  -1 value , and you pass to onProgressUpdate(-1) . this is your problem .
change Integer by Boolean

Comment: Well, it just means that you cannot easily use the content length to calculate the progress. But it wouldn't make much sense anyway. In the code shown above you call publishProgress() only once so the progress bar would progress only once. Your code isn't running a loop. It won't update the progress bar continuously. The indeterminate progress bar makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

do sth like this :

in `doInBackground` you must check if your work is correct or not .
if you do well , then , you must pass true to `onProgressUpdate` . if not , you must pass false to `onProgressUpdate` .
the structure of onProgressUpdate must be like this :

```
onProgressUpdate(boolean flag)
```

for increase value of progressD (0 , 100) you must do it in your doInBackground method .

```
if (status == 404) {
                intValueOfProgress = 0;
}
if (status == 200) {
                intValueOfProgress = 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, this doesn't say much sir